# Can we receive images using MQTT in android?

Tags: android, mqtt, mosquitto

I thought of using MQTT with Mosquito to transfer images between android devices.
And if the receiving device is not using the internet when the image is sent, will it receive the image when it comes online.

Answer (score 0):

MQTT messages have a pure byte payload so can send anything you want (up to a limit of about 260mb) so yes you can send images.

As for having them delivered if the client is off line. Assuming the client has connected and subscribed to the topic the message is sent on in the past and is not using the cleansession flag then messages should be queued.

Have a look at this blog post about persistent subscriptions: 
http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages